# ECSlidingViewController remove PanGesture

Tags: ios, ecslidingviewcontroller

The setup in Storyboard:

> NavigationController >> AViewController >> BViewController

I am using `ECSlidingViewController 2.0`, I want to remove the panGesture for `BViewController`, I put the code in `BViewController` under `-(void)viewWillAppear`. but `AVideController` also removed the panGesture. am i doing wrong ?

```
[self.navigationController.view removeGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[self.view removeGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];
```

Hope this helps.. :)